# Particular class element in a beatutiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i have below html text     `<div class="jtxt" title="abcd"></div> <div class="jtxt orange">  <span>Confidential</span>`
'
 i want to print only abcd i.e part of class=jtxt and not include jtxt jco 
when i print    `a.findAll("div",{"class":"jtxt"})` all title is getting printed . i don't want any restirction based on index where is it getting printed . Is there any way to restrict `class="jtxt"`  not containing  `"jtxt"` .
I am doing above code in python using beautiful soup

Answer (score 1):

You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary. You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div class="jtxt" title="abcd"></div> <div class="jtxt orange">  <span>Confidential</span>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('div',class_='jtxt')['title'])
```

Output

```
abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4

html = '''<div class="jtxt" title="abcd"></div> <div class="jtxt orange">  <span>Confidential</span>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('div')['title']

print (title)
```

**Output:**

```
'abcd'
```